# Method of local ejb threw exception

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, local

We are migrating our java applications from WAS 7 to WAS 8.5. After logging into  one of our application we are calling a local ejb method from controller to get details for an id. The method gets called,it queries the data, but when returning to controller it errors out giving, Method of local EJB threw exception. Would be great if someone could shed some light on the issue. I have checked multiple forums, but couldn't get a proper explanation. Below is the stack trace.

I've mentioned some places as "package name" as it cannot be shared.

```
javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException:  ; nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.stage3CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1251)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1042)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:963)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:439)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.commit(TranStrategy.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.RequiresNew.postInvoke(RequiresNew.java:154)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4491)
    at <package name>EJSLocalStatelessInvestigationProcessingService_8d39cc4e.epGetDetailsForInvestigationProcessing(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor.invokeInContext(LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.invoke(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:188)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.epGetDetailsForInvestigationProcessing(Unknown Source)
    at <package name>.processGetRequest(MaintainInvestigationController.java:286)
    at com.pmigroup.jpmiframework.web.mvc.controller.ApplMultiActionFormController.showForm(ApplMultiActionFormController.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.showNewForm(AbstractFormController.java:338)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:278)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
```

The caused by trace is as follows.

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException:  ; nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.stage3CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1251)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1042)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:963)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:439)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.commit(TranStrategy.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.RequiresNew.postInvoke(RequiresNew.java:154)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4491)
    at <package_name>EJSLocalStatelessInvestigationProcessingService_8d39cc4e.epGetDetailsForInvestigationProcessing(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor.invokeInContext(LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.invoke(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:188)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.epGetDetailsForInvestigationProcessing(Unknown Source)
    at <package_name>.processGetRequest(MaintainInvestigationController.java:286)
    at <package_name>.showForm(ApplMultiActionFormController.java:269)
```

Comment: I don't work with WAS but from the stack trace above, I can guess that you're invoking an EJB that has a "TransactionAttribute" REQUIRES_NEW that had thrown a RuntimeException causing the transaction to Rollback. Check during startup if something with your deployement of EJB/Spring went wrong and add a try catch block inside the method to isolate the specific exception, alternatively attach a debugger.

Comment: There should be a `Caused by` that has more information.

Comment: @BrettKail The caused by also shows the same trace. Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException:  ; nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.stage3CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1251)
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1042)
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:963)
        at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.

Comment: @Vimal I suggest editing the post to show the entire chain of `Caused by`.

Comment: @Vimal It says `nested exception`, which implies there is yet another stack trace following this one.  Is there?